# Add html to json content in an NG-Repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im repeating objects of JSON using NG-Repeat. How do I include html, such as a link, in here:

```
        {id: "53",  description: "here is a <a href = '#/detail/'>Link</a> to something", additional: ["2.jpg", "3.jpg" ]}
```

Comment: Can you give us some context? What have you tried? What's not working with what you've tried?

Comment: Its showing up as text and not html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$sce` to trust the HTML. I like to create a filter and use `ng-bind-html` on a `<span>` tag. Using a filter makes it super simple to show HTML wherever you need. Here is a simple example.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .filter('unsafe', ($sce) => {
    return function(value) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
    }
  })
  .controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {
    $scope.items = [{
        id: "53",
        description: "here is a <a href = '#/detail/'>Link</a> to something",
        additional: ["2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
      },
      {
        id: "54",
        description: "here is another <a href = '#/detail/'>Link</a> to something",
        additional: ["4.jpg", "5.jpg"]
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items"><span ng-bind-html="item.description | unsafe"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```